# Using Configuration API in drupal 8

Tags: 8, configuration

I altered node_type_edit_form and added a section to get some settings like below:

[image: Node type form]

Now I need to save the configurations and build the default value based on last selection using **Configuration API** .

The problem is it needs to build the fields selected (checkbox) in every content type form.

Comment: Do you want the settings for each content type or for all the content types?

Comment: I need unique settings for each content type that admin has selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having your own configuration files, you can also use the third party settings concept to add your configuration directly to the node type config entity.

There are multiple advantages in doing that, you don't need to worry about cleaning up when node types are deleted, it's easier to deploy/export node types with their information and it's also easy to access/write when you have a node type. See the relevant change records: https://www.drupal.org/node/2326151 and https://www.drupal.org/node/2419827.

menu_ui.module has a great example for this in core, look for the functions `menu_ui_form_node_type_form_alter()`, `menu_ui_form_node_type_form_builder()` (or as an alternative of the builder, define your form structure so that it's saved in the right third party settings key automatically) and the config schema in `menu_ui.schema.yml`.

Comment: This is more than what I expected!!. But I cannot exactly understand the use of menu_ui.schema.yml. Can you please add some details about this in your answer berdir. It would be so helpful.

Comment: All configuration needs to be defined by a schema, so that the types are known and can be enforced, translations are possible and so on. Just take that as an example and adjust it for your module name, keys and so on. You just need the node.type.*.third_party.menu_ui part, where menu_ui is our module name and then the keys below is what you save in there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have machine name of `content type` while altering `node_type_edit_form`. So I assume that `$node_type` is the variable in which machine name can be accessible.

So as stated in drupal [list changes](https://www.drupal.org/node/2183531), `variable_get` and `variable_set` is replaced by config system in drupal 8.

To save a configuration you need to add this code in your submit function :

```
\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('modulename.settings')
    ->set('checkboxsetting_' . $node_type, $form_state->getValues()['checkboxsettings'])
    ->set('radiosettings' . $node_type, $form_state->getValues()['radiosettings'])
    ->save();
```

and to get the saved values you need to :

```
\Drupal::config('modulename.settings')->get('checkboxsetting_' . $node_type);
```

To set the default configuration from yml file. Create a yml file and content will be :

**modulename/config/install/modulename.settings.yml**

```
checkboxsetting_page: whatever
checkboxsetting_article: whatever
radio_page: whatever
radio_article: whatever
```

Comment: Thanks sumit but what I need to know is how the YML(schema) for this type of configuration is built.

Comment: Means?? Do you need to create a yml too for default configuration?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear on this. I need to know how to build the YML schema to store these values. Are YML schemas required only to build default values??

Comment: Updated my answer.